# Markdown - return text instead of empty table if no rows are returned

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Useing markdown to/knitr produce a report. I use the following to select the rows missing values from a dataframe and displaying them as a table in my output.

```
    z <- df[is.na(df$colnamne1) | is.na(df$colname2) | is.na(df$colname3), ]
    z <- select(z, colname1, colname2, colname3)

    kable(z)
```

This creates a nice table if there are missing values. If there are no missing values, I would like it to return a text message "none missing" instead of an empty table in my word/PDF/html when generating the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an `if` statement will handle this nicely. Just have it check for if the number of rows in your `z` dataframe is equal to 0. If not, print the table! Below is a small example to replicate this.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
```{r, comment = NA, echo = FALSE}
library('knitr')

df <- data.frame(colname1 = c(3, 1, 2),
                 colname2 = c(7, 3, 5),
                 colname3 = c(7, 8, 4))

# Uncomment the lines below to see how it handles data with NA values.
# df <- data.frame(colname1 = c(NA, 1, 2),
#                  colname2 = c(NA, 3, 5),
#                  colname3 = c(7, 8, NA))

z <- df[is.na(df$colname1) | is.na(df$colname2) | is.na(df$colname3), ]
z <- z[, c('colname1', 'colname2', 'colname3')]

if(nrow(z) == 0){
  cat('None Missing')
} else{
  kable(z)
}

```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a nicer format for the text. I would suggest tweaking @Sam's answer with

```
if(nrow(z) == 0){
kable(NULL, caption = 'No records available') 
} else{
  kable(z)
}
```

Still not perfect, but at least it mirrors the font of your document.